# When an element is dragged from Storyboard to ViewController, where is it linked programmatically?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

As I understand it, each element such as a button or label is linked from Storyboard to ViewController. This is done graphically in XCode by dragging. Where is the code that states this pairing in the XCode environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *no* code that states this. In fact, there is no actual connection being made at all. It's just an illusion.

There are two *separate* things being configured when you do that:

- In the *nib* (the storyboard), an outlet is configured. It is just a name, a string
- In the code, there is a property with the same name.

The connection between them happens, if it is going to happen at all, when the app actually runs and at some point the nib is *loaded*. At that moment, the nib has an *owner*, and *key-value coding* is used to look for a property of that owner with the same name as the outlet. If it's there, the object instantiated from the nib is assigned as the value of that property, and thus the connection is made.

So you see, there is no real connection in Xcode. There are two *separate* things that will need to try to connect while the app actually runs, at nib-loading time. It's a fragile and risky business. That is why, if there is *no* such property, your app crashes at that moment.

Comment: This is actually the answer I was hoping to get. Maybe programmatically was not the correct word, I wanted to know if there was some key-value pairing in some XML somewhere

Comment: Described in excruciating detail, with diagrams, in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_outlet_connections

Answer (score 1):

Basically @IBOutlet is not part of Swift, and that's what lets Xcode figure out that outlet property inside a controller is linked to some UIView (or subclass, such as UILabel) on the Storyboard.

Also, if you right-click the Storyboard, and Open As > Source Code, you should see a lot of the generated UI/XML code. If your label is called myLabel, you should see something like this:

```
<connections>
    <outlet property="myLabel" destination="zLp-2i-ru4" id="Zda-UD-1h6"/>
</connections>
```

inside one of the Scene Nodes.